# A relaxation of Lipschitz Functions

Tags: functions, continuity

I want to find fucnctions close to Lipschitz functions. A function $f$ is Lipschitz if $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq C|x - y|$ for all $x$ and $y$, where $C$ is a constant independent of $x$ and $y$.

The function $g$ in which I am interested has the following property:
$|g(x) - g(y)| \leq \sigma(|x - y|)$ for all $x$ and $y$, where $\sigma$ is a comparison function which obeys: $\sigma(0) = 0, \lim_{s \rightarrow +\infty}\sigma(s) = +\infty$ and $\sigma$ is strictly increasing continuous function.

Obvisouly a Lipschitz function has the above property. Is there any function that is not Lipschitz but also has the above property?

Comment: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder_condition

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity